# Phonegap app can't access ajax after first launch

Tags: javascript, android, ajax, cordova, phonegap

Whenever I install my app for the first time, it can't make an ajax request, but if I close and reopen it works normally, what can this be? This problem does not happen on all devices, just some, usually samsung with android pie.

This problem did not occur before, only when assigning api 28 to targetsdk that this problem appeared

Also this error does not appear when the application is in debug mode

Comment: Simply update Chrome to new version. Its Chromium bug.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out the cause of the problem, the cause was this bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=991107, so if you make requests through a library like jquery or the XMLHttpRequest class itself, and set targetApi to 28 in your cordova or phonegap project will go through this, this problem usually occurs to users who have chrome mobile version 76.0.3809.89, so in the end, the solution was to execute the requests on native layer (android), who is having the same problem I recommend using this plugin to perform the requests: https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP